# Reviewing over 600 version conflicts?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I'm fairly new to working with versioned geodatabases and have found that one of my versions has over 600 conflicts which require review and replacing.

I suspect that all objects will need to be replaced with the Conflict Version, but I would like to confirm my suspicions.

Is there a quick / automated way to review all of them without going through one by one?

I'm relatively new to learning Python too.

Comment: I'm assuming this is ArcSDE data of some sort. Can you add additional details on what version you're running?

Comment: Yes it is ArcSDE data and running ArcGIS version 10.3.  Since I asked this question, I have another issue.  I worked thought a number of these conflicts, but since returning to it, I can no longer find them and the conflicts icon is greyed out! I have no idea what step I'm missing.  If you have any advise on this that would be great!